# iFrame not identifying by Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, iframe, webdriver, identification

This is my first time posting a question. I have spent over 3 days trying to figure out how to identify iFrame by webdriver. Here is my html code:

```
<iframe id="emailBodyIframe" class="" frameborder="0" src="about:blank" style="height: 151px;">
<html>
<head>
<body>
<p>Dear Administrator,</p>
Here is a passport number : XXXXXXX
<span class="sv-b212-highlighting" style="background-color:#B9DFF5;">aba</span>
#: 0000-0000-0
<p>Regards,</p>
<p>Local Archive</p>
</body>
```

Here is the code that is giving me error

```
FRAME = self.driver.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe").text
self.driver.switch_to().frame(FRAME)
body1 = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.sv-b212-highlighting").text
print body1
#self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.sv-b212-highlighting").text
#self.driver.switch_to.frame(highlight,self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("iframe[id='emailBodyIframe']").text)
```

- The error I am getting is

AttributeError: SwitchTo instance has no **call** method

- My question is

How to identify the highlighted CSS that is inside an iFrame?

I have tried a few other variations with other code examples that was provided on this website. All are returning with different errors. I am new to python and still learning.

Anyone knows how I can do that?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get web-element, while with your `FRAME` variable you intend to get only text from `iframe`. Try to use following code:

```
self.driver.switch_to_frame("emailBodyIframe")
body1 = self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("span.sv-b212-highlighting").text
print body1
```

You don't have to add `.text` if you want to handle element. Use it only to get text value from web-element

Comment: Thanks Andersson. Unfortunately, that didn't work. I am getting an error : NoSuchElementException: Message

Comment: try `body1 = self.driver.find_element_by_xpath('//span[contains(@class, "highlighting"]').text`